# Use bash to read a file and then execute a command from the words extracted

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting, loops

FILE:

```
hello
world
```

I would like to use a scripting language (**BASH**) to execute a command that reads each `WORD` in the `FILE` above and then plugs it into a `command`.

It then loops to the next word in the list (each word on new line).
It stops when it reaches the end of the `FILE`.

---

**Progression would be similar to this:**

Read first `WORD` from `FILE` above

Plug word into command

```
command WORD > WORD
```

- which will output it to a text file; with word as the name of the file.

Repeat this process, but with next to nth `WORD` (each on a new line).

Terminate process upon reaching the end of `FILE` above.

---

**Result of BASH command on** `FILE` above:

hello:

```
RESULT OF COMMAND UPON WORD hello
```

world:

```
RESULT OF COMMAND UPON WORD world
```

Comment: No - its a hobby-project to create a list of all French Verb conjugations from a large list of French verbs.

Comment: 800 French Verbs -> french-conjugator (debian) -> Create a directory of conjugations -> Make Flash Cards -> I'll publish the link when I'm done (quizet.com).

Comment: @ghostdog74 - How could you doubt me? You've been helping me for a couple of days ;) with text manipulation under *nix systems. I guess the question does look a bit homeworky - but I made it so that others may benefit via my abstraction. Else I could've just plugged in what I wanted.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can use the "for" loop to do this. something like..

```
for WORD in `cat FILE`
do
   echo $WORD
   command $WORD > $WORD
done
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! As did those below - but included files with odd characters (apostrophes). Should've put that in the question - but I tried to abstract it as much as possible.

Answer (score 20):

normally i would ask what have you tried.

```
while read -r line 
do 
   command ${line} > ${line}.txt
done< "file"
```

Answer (score 9):

```
IFS=$'\n';for line in `cat FILEPATH`; do command ${line} > ${line}; done
```