# How to create a loop using values from a different file?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, find

I have a file containing following numbers
file1.txt

```
1
5
6
8
14
```

I have another file named rmsd.txt which contains values like the following

```
1 2.12
2 3.1243
3 4.156
4 3.22
5 3.882
6 8.638
7 8.838
8 7.5373
9 10.7373
10 8.3527
11 3.822
12 5.672
13 7.23
14 5.9292
```

I want to get the values of column 2 from rmsd.txt for the numbers present in file.txt. I want to get something like the following

```
1 2.12
5 3.882
6 8.638
8 7.5373
14 5.9292
```

I can do that by do like that `grep 1 rmsd.txt` and so on but it will take a long time. I was trying a for loop something like

```
for a in awk '{print $1}' file.txt; do
grep $a rmsd.txt >result.txt
done
```

But it didn't work. Maybe it is very simple and I am thinking in a wrong direction. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How is this asked every single day... Did you try searching `how to match field from one file in another` on google?

Answer (score 0):

```
for WORD in `cat FILE`
do
   echo $WORD
   command $WORD > $WORD
done
```

[Origina source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605232/use-bash-to-read-a-file-and-then-execute-a-command-from-the-words-extracted)

EDIT: Here is your code with few fixes:

```
for a in `awk '{print $1}' file.txt`
do
    grep $a rmsd.txt >>result.txt
done
```

Comment: Oh I see you already got it. But you missed backticks in your version.

Answer (score 0):

This is tailor made job for `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $1 in a' file1.txt msd.txt

1 2.12
5 3.882
6 8.638
8 7.5373
14 5.9292
```

Most likely it a duplicate, as soon as I find a good dup, I will mark it so.

Comment: lol how many times have you posted this exact answer.

Comment: lol :) I was going to write that it is most likely a dup but I am unable to find exact dup for now

Comment: same here, easier to type than search.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} $1 in a' file1 file2

1 2.12
5 3.882
6 8.638
8 7.5373
14 5.9292
```

or with `sort/join`

```
$ join <(sort file1) <(sort file2) | sort -n
```

or `grep/sed`

```
$ grep -f <(sed 's/.*/^&\\b/' file1) file2
```